# Serializing rxjs Observable to custom business objects

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs5

How do i serialize an rxjs observable returned by an http call to my business object? sample is mentioned below

myData.json:

```
[{
    "prop1" : "val1",
    "prop2" : "val2",
    "prop3" : "val3",
    "prop4" : "val4",
  }, {
    "prop1" : "val11",
    "prop2" : "val22",
    "prop3" : "val33",
    "prop4" : "val44",
  },......]
```

Observable:

```
 this.myData$ = this._http.get('/data/myData.json')
                  .map(response => <any[]>response.json());
```

template:

```
 <ul>
  <li class="text" *ngFor="let item of myData$ | async">
    {{item.prop1}} - {{item.prop2}} - {{item.prop3}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

everything works great with the above code, but i need to transform the JSON objects received asynchronously to instances of a different business objects and still bind asynchronously to the template. How do i achieve this. which rxjs operator let me achieve this?

My business class is:

```
export class Custom {

    prop10: string;
    prop20: string;

    constructor(data) {
        this.prop10 = this.evaluate(data.prop1);
        this.prop20 = data.prop2;

    }
    private evaluate(val): string {
        // do some custom business rules....
        return "something";
    }
}
```

my actual template

```
<ul>
  <li class="text" *ngFor="let item of myData$ | async">
    {{item.prop10}} - {{item.prop20}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple additional `.map`, where you map each array-entry inside should work:

```
this.myData$ = this._http.get('/data/myData.json')
                  .map(response => <any[]>response.json())
                  .map(items => items.map(item => new Custom(item));
```

Comment: thats was easy :)  thanks! I guess i should learn rxjs operators in depth to understand how it works.